# Server restart causes MySQL replication to break

Tags: mysql

I have encountered an issue with MySQL replication . I have configured MySQL replication from local physical server to AWS EC2 Instance.Under normal circumstances it performs as intended, but it breaks when slave server i.e, EC2 Instance restarts.

Comment: Even if this is off-topic here: you should attach some kind of log or error message to your question

Comment: For clean server restart you should to stop mysql before restart server